# Convert one-document-per-line to Blei's lda-c/dtm format for topic modeling?

Tags: nlp, dataform, lda

I am doing Latent Dirichlet Analyses for some research and keep running into a problem. Most lda software requires documents to be in doclines format, meaning a CSV or other delimited file in which each line represents the entirety of a document. However, [Blei's lda-c](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/lda-c/readme.txt) and dynamic topic model software requires that data be in the format: `[M] [term_1]:[count] [term_2]:[count] ...  [term_N]:[count]` where `[M]` is the number of unique terms in the document, and the [count] associated with each term is how many times that term appeared
in the document.  Note that `[term_1]` is an integer which indexes the
term; it is not a string.

Does anyone know of a utility that will let me quickly convert to this format? Thank you.

Comment: I meet similar problems, do you happen to find the solutions? Thanks.

Comment: I have not implemented it yet, but [this Python utility](https://github.com/JoKnopp/text2ldac) was posted to the topic models mailing list and is supposed to take text files and convert them to the correct format.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with `R`, the `lda` package contains a function `lexicalize` that will convert raw text into the lda-c format necessary for the `lda` package.

```
example <- c("I am the very model of a modern major general",
             "I have a major headache")

corpus <- lexicalize(example, lower=TRUE)
```

Similarly, the `topicmodels` package has a function `dtm2ldaformat` that will convert a document term matrix to the lda format. You can convert a plain text document into a document term matrix using the `tm` package, also in `R`.

So with these existing functions there's a lot of flexibility in getting text into `R` for topic modelling.

Answer (score 2):

The Mallet package from University of Massachusetts Amherst is another option.

- http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/
- http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/topics.php

And here is an excellent step-by-step demo on how to use Mallet:

- http://programminghistorian.org/lessons/topic-modeling-and-mallet

You can use mallet with just normal text files as input source.

Answer (score 1):

Gensim offers an implementation of Blei's corpus format. See [here](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/bleicorpus.html). You could write a quick corpus based on your CSV file in [Python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and then save it in lda-c with gensim. It should not be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

For Python, there is an available function for this(may not be available at the time of the question).

```
lda.utils.dtm2ldac
```

The document is https://pythonhosted.org/lda/api.html#module-lda.utils